# Unable to select row; Index out of range

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am having an issue with my application, i am trying to use the same code i have used for other sections of my application for a new page but i keep getting an error.  Thisis what happens exactly:  I have a gridview with "auto generate select button" set to "true" now when you click the select button of a specific row the following code is executed:

```
private void DisplayDetails()
    {
        int rowIndex = dtGridViewList.SelectedIndex;
        GridViewRow Row = dtGridViewList.SelectedRow;

        cmbCompany.SelectedValue = dtGridViewList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["CompanyID"].ToString();
        cmbDept.SelectedValue = dtGridViewList.DataKeys[rowIndex].Values["DeptID"].ToString();

        txtProject.Text = Row.Cells[1].Text;
        cmbCompany.SelectedValue = Row.SelectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
        cmbDept.SelectedValue = Row.Cells[3].Text;
        txtStartDate.Text = Row.Cells[4].Text;
        txtEndDate.Text = Row.Cells[5].Text;
        cmbManager.SelectedValue = Row.Cells[6].Text;
        cmbLocation.SelectedValue = Row.Cells[7].Text;
        txtNotes.Text = Row.Cells[6].Text;

    }
```

This function is executed in the gridviews "SelectedIndexChanged" event:

```
protected void dtGridViewList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (dtGridViewList.SelectedIndex >= 0)
            {
                pnlProjectList.Enabled = true;
                DisplayDetails();
            }
            else
            {
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('Not Selected!');</SCRIPT>");
            }
    }
```

However the code stops executing at:

```
GridViewRow Row = dtGridViewList.SelectedRow;
```

With the error:

```
Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

I have used the same code for other pages and it has worked pretty well soo far so i am unable to understand why it does not work for his page.

Comment: Have you confirmed that dtGridViewList contains data at the time you call it - i.e. is it getting called as part of a post back, or is it being ran during PageLoad?

Comment: Yes the data is displayed right infront of me and the function that populates the gridview is run on page load not during postback.

Comment: Can you show more of the code, specifically what is in the SelectedIndexChanged method?

Comment: Would it be worth using the `SelectedIndexChanged` and/or `SelectedIndexChanging` methods to set the selected row? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.selectedrow.aspx

Comment: I have made an edit, adding what exactly is in my selectedIndexChanged method.

Comment: And as for whether to use SelectedIndexChanged or SelectedIndexChanging i have been using "SelectedIndexChanged" with working results for the same thing so far.

Comment: did you add runat='server' property for dtGridViewList in design page?

Comment: Yes i did add the runat="sever" in fact because i dragged and dropped from the toolbox it was added automatically.

Comment: What is `rowIndex` right before the program bombs out?

Comment: rowIndex = 0, that is for the first record.

Comment: could you please show us where yu are binding the data  to datagridview?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay thank you all alot for your contributions but i managed to solve the problem.
This is what i did before:

1. I set the datasource of the gridview dynamically using a function i
   created that returned a dataset and used the first
   table(dataset.Tables[0]) as the datasource for the gridview.
2. I added the boundfields using the "edit columns" interface of the
   gridview graphically.

Now it happens that i was getting this problem because of step 2, i still do not know why because i have tried it before on other pages and it worked perfectly.

This is what i did to correct the problem:

1. I set "auto generate columns" in the gridview property list to
   "true".
2. I removed all the bound fields that i had added to the
       gridview.
3. In the code behind i set the visibility of columns i did
       not want to show to "false
           (Mainly ID Columns)

And that is what i did to solve my problem, i would like to have some insight on why i had this problem in the first place.